# Separate joined mesh for kitbashing

Tags: objects, edit-mode, obj

I have an imported .obj with several pieces that I want to seperate for [kitbashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitbashing), but instead of doing one by one is there a way to automate it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're almost there! Just Select All in Edit mode then P > Separate by Loose Parts on that menu.

Comment: Yeah that's right but when i use that option i come with a lot of splitted parts which i have to re-join after https://i.imgur.com/v90B3Y0.png :-s